# Validating Excel using XML and moving to SQL Server destination

Tags: t-sql

Is there a built in function (as opposed to a UDF) or can someone provide sample code to split a String to two columns when a character is encountered?
Sample:

1234:abcd

split the above string into 1234 and abcd into two columns

Comment: Is there always a colon? Is it dropped so that it goes in neither column? Do any letters always appear after the colon? It might be helpful if you showed examples of all of the possible combinations here by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Title/tag mismatch?

For Excel, if `A1` contains the value:

make `B1` `=LEFT(A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",A1)),LEN(A1),FIND(":",A1)-1))`
make `C1` `=RIGHT(A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",A1)),0,LEN(A1)-FIND(":",A1)))`

Or for T-SQL + a string variable;

```
DECLARE @F VARCHAR(64) = '1234:ABCD'

IF @F LIKE '%:%' 
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@F, 1, CHARINDEX(':', @F, 1) - 1) AS COL1, 
            SUBSTRING(@F, CHARINDEX(':', @F, 1) + 1, LEN(@F)) AS COL2
ELSE
    SELECT @F AS COL1, NULL AS COL2
```

for a select;

```
;WITH faketable (fld) AS (
    SELECT 'aaa:123' as fld
    UNION SELECT 'ddddd'
)
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN fld LIKE '%:%' THEN SUBSTRING(fld, 1, CHARINDEX(':', fld, 1) - 1) ELSE fld END AS COL1 ,
    CASE WHEN fld LIKE '%:%' THEN SUBSTRING(fld, CHARINDEX(':', fld, 1) + 1, LEN(fld)) ELSE NULL END AS COL2 
FROM faketable

>COL1   COL2
>aaa    123
>ddddd  NULL
```

Comment: I was looking for a simple tsql statement..your suggestions helped..thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this. Its not pretty but it produces the two columns (assuming : is always the divider):

```
declare @test varchar(20)
set @test = '1234:abcd'

select 
    leftcol = left(@test,charindex(':',@test)-1),
    rightcol = right(@test,len(@test) - charindex(':',@test))
```

In otherwords, its not a build in function, but it is inline sql code.